# Load component/template depending on the route param vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to ask if can I implement this on vuejs, so basically the code will load a page/template base on the param url. I've been searching for a while and can't get the results I need or maybe I'm just searching a wrong keyword.

My url is like this, so I just can't manually declare the url in my route because it is dynamic, fetch from the database.

```
path: '/user/page_type
```

Thank you very much!

```
export default {
    mounted () {
        if(this.$routes.params.page_type == "home"){
            // Load Homepage Here
            // ../../../page/HomePage.vue
        }
        else if(this.$routes.params.page_type == "speaker"){
            // Load Speakerpage Here
            // ../../../page/HomePage.vue
        }
        else if(this.$routes.params.page_type == 'html'){
            // Load HTML Page Here
            // ../../../page/HtmlPage.vue
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is available out of the box within official addon `vue-router`.

Docs for your case: [link](http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Comment: My scenario is it will render different component based on params. Not the same component

Comment: Then in your /user/ component you can insert `<component :is="getComponent"></component>` and in script set `watch: { '$route': { ...` like described here http://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html (Reacting to Params Changes). In method getComponent you can return desired component name.

Comment: do you have any example for this `<component :is="getComponent"></component>` I'm quite didn't understand. would you mind to share some links that I can check?

Comment: Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/yLu0uza8/2/ . Dynamic components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: You're the best Man!. This is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much!