# How can I get component depends on vue router param?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a component `Portfolio.vue` which has child component `Category.vue` where I can get by `<router-link :to = "{ name: 'category', params: { id: id }}">`. `Category.vue` receives param `id` from router.
In `Category.vue` I want to import one of many components. For example, if `id` that `Category.vue` gets from `Portfolio.vue` = 'google', so I have `id = 'google'`, and I want to import component `google.vue` inside `Category.vue` and render it there.

Here is my `Portfolio.vue` snippet

```
<template>
    <div class = "categories">
                        <div
                                class = "category"
                                v-for = "(category, index) in categories"
                                :key = "index"
                        >
                            <div class = "category-title">{{category.name}}</div>
                            <div class = "category-description">{{category.description}}</div>
                            <div class = "category-portfolios">
                                <div
                                        class = "category-portfolio"
                                        v-for = "(portfolio, index) in category.portfolios"
                                        :key = "index"
                                >
                                    <router-link :to = "{ name: 'category', params: { slug: portfolio.slug }}">
                                        {{portfolio.slug}}
                                    </router-link>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "portfolio",
        data() {
            return {
                pageName: 'Portfolio',
                categories: []
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            fetch('api/portfolio/index')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(json => this.categories = Object.assign({}, json.categories))

                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })

        }
    }
</script>

<style lang = "scss" scoped>
   
</style>
```

Here is my `Category.vue`

```
    <template>
        <div>
            {{slug}}
            <component
                    :is="currentTabComponent"
                    class="test"
            ></component> <!--this component should be rendered-->
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    // import this.$route.params.slug   from './components/portfolios/this.$route.params.slug' 
//this code is wrong, but the main idea is to import component

        export default {
            name: "category",
            data() {
                return {
                    slug: ''
                }
            },
            beforeCreate() {
                this.slug = this.$route.params.slug;
            },
            computed: {
                // maybe here I should definded what component should I render. This was in example in Vue documentation
                currentTabComponent: function () {
                    return this.slug
                }
            },
    
        }
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
    
    </style>
```

And my `google.vue` component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>This is google portfolio</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "google"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I read this [Load component/template depending on the route param vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555711/load-component-template-depending-on-the-route-param-vuejs) and watched this https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/yLu0uza8/2/ and this https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components, but I still can't get how can I import specific `.vue` component from folder/file, how can I declare this specific `.vue` component in parent component (`Category.vue`) and at last how can I render this specific `.vue` component in parent component (`Category.vue`) `<template></template>`.

So the main question how can I import specific component by router param from the number of components?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) and pass the `id` param [as props](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components) to your route.
Something like:

```
const Category = Vue.component('category', {
  name: 'category',
  template: '#category',
  props: ['id']
});

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/category/:id', name: 'category', component: Category, props: true },
  ]
})
```

and in template:

```
<template id="category">
  <div>
    <h3>Category : {{ id }}</h3>
    <component :is="id"></component>
  </div>
</template>
```

*[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/StpFlp_DDK/681yz5fg/)*

Answer (score -1):

Couldn´t you just make the component itself dynamicly change its content based on the route id?

Comment: How can I do this? Where from the content should be?

Comment: And there are will be a lot of static html inside every child component, and different design

Comment: @YaroslavSaenko hard to say i dont have any code or any thing other than the name of your components...